# Access Form simple VBA password with 3 attempts code

Tags: vba

I am trying to have simple password entry before opening a report in Access that allows 3 attempts and then closes the form. This is what I came up with but I am having a bit of trouble putting it together, any help is appreciated

Thanks

```
Option Compare Database
'after clicking the button, the user must have the password to open  the   Report

Private Sub btnOpenPayrollReport_Click()
'I need this to be the password

Dim password As String
password = "coke"
If InputBox("Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password")  <>     password Then

DoCmd.OpenReport "Payroll", acViewReport, "", "", acNormal
 Exit Sub
    Else

'I need to allow the user 3 attempts before closing the form

intLogonAttempts = intLogonAttempts + 1
If intLogonAttempts > 3 Then
DoCmd.Close
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you explain what specific error or problem you are having?

Comment: Hi, the program just doesn't seem to work this way...basically I just need to enter a password -> then if its correct open the report. If not then use an attempt and say "wrong pass" after 3 wrong attempts -> close the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to do this with a loop:

```
Private Sub btnOpenPayrollReport_Click()
'I need this to be the password
Dim i As Integer
Dim password As String
password = "coke"
For i = 1 To 3
    If InputBox("Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password") = password Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Payroll", acViewReport, "", "", acNormal
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "The password is incorrect.  You have " & 3 - i & " Attemps", vbExclamation & vbOK
    End If
    'I need to allow the user 3 attempts before closing the form
Next i

DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```

This way if it ever gets to the end of the loop it just closes.  This automatically pops up the next try.

If you want the original button to be the initiator then using a public variable that is put outside the code on top of the module use this:

```
Public intLogonAttempts As Integer

Private Sub btnOpenPayrollReport_Click()
'I need this to be the password

Dim password As String
password = "coke"
If InputBox("Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password") = password Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Payroll", acViewReport, "", "", acNormal
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "The password is incorrect.  You have " & 3 - i & " Attemps", vbExclamation & vbOK
End If
    'I need to allow the user 3 attempts before closing the form

If intLogonAttempts >= 3 Then DoCmd.Close
intLogonAttempts = intLogonAttempts + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott,  that is exactly what I was trying to do. I'm gonna try it with a textbox as well.

Comment: @ZweiiHander glad I could help.